# Как заполнить вектор большим количеством элементов

Tags: c++

Знаю заранее 10^7 чисел, которые нужны для того, чтобы заполнить ими вектор. Как это сделать? Пробовал вот так `a[10000000]={1,....,33}`, но так не получается. Буду признателен за подсказку.

Comment: Не понятно, какими значениями вы собираетесь инициализировать массив. Вы же не хотите вручную указать  10000000 значений, не так ли?

Comment: Проблема в том, что ваше знание вы должны как-то донести до компилятора :)

Comment: А как можно это сделать?Чисел много, поэтому занимает памяти больше 64кб,неужели не существует способа наполнить вектор числами,если они уже мне известны?

Comment: Ну, а чем вам не подошло `vector<int> v { 2015, 42, 18, 2048, 9999, -1, 7, -273, 0, 666 <и далее по списку>}`?

Comment: Если числа известны _вам_, этого не достаточно. Они должны стать известны компилятору. Поэтому или вы перечисляете их все, либо кодируете правило, по которому они вычисляются (если оно есть).

Comment: @user191682  Я еще раз спрашиваю, какими значениями вы собираетесь инициализировать элементы массива?!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел кое-какую информацию о векторах и их наполнении - [Источник](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/)

Вот алгоритм наполнения вектора

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::fill
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector (8);                       // myvector: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

  std::fill (myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+4,5);   // myvector: 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0
  std::fill (myvector.begin()+3,myvector.end()-2,8);   // myvector: 5 5 5 8 8 8 0 0

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

На выходе:

`myvector contains: 5 5 5 8 8 8 0 0`

Comment: Это не причина лепить минуса просто так

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение!

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что для 10^7 элементов Вам будет нужна отдельная единица компиляции.

В gcc (не g++) массив из 20 элементов можно инициализировать вот так

```
int arr[] = {[1 ... 10] = 2, 33, [14] = 40, 41, 42, [19] = 50};
```

(указывая индексы, необязательно по порядку).

Т.е. здесь элементы с `arr[1]` по `arr[10]` будут равны 2, `arr[11]` 33 и т.д. (думаю очевидно), а явно не инициализированные -- 0.

Как задать формулу для вычисления последовательности при инициализации -- не знаю (и есть ли такая возможность?), но такие диапазоны можно инициализировать вызовом функций.

А далее - перенести массив в вектор -- думаю это уже тривиально.

Answer (score 0):

Если надо скопировать данные из массива в вектор, то можно сделать просто:

```
int a[10000000]={1,....,33};
vector<int> v1(a, a + 10000000);
```

Вы эти числа 10^7 будите вставлять в код или брать из файла? Если из файла, то можно считывать по одной цифре, далее приводить к типу int и вставлять в вектор
a.push_back(value);

Comment: А выражение `int a[10000000]={1,....,33};` чем компилируется?

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и, с моей точки зрения, правильный вариант — это использовать файл, где числа записаны через пробел. Это в том случае, если числа заранее были вычислены. Тогда, имея файл `test.txt`, наполненный, скажем, `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`, мы можем написать следующий код для получения всех значений:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    copy(istream_iterator<int>{file}, istream_iterator<int>{}, back_inserter(numbers));
    cout << "Numbers: \n";
    for(auto number : numbers)
        cout << number << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Если же значения заранее не вычислены, тогда имеет смысл использовать алгоритм `generate_n`, в который передавать функцию вычисления каждого значения:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    int counter = 0;
    generate_n(back_inserter(numbers), 10, [&] {return counter++;});
    cout << "Numbers: \n";
    for(auto number : numbers)
        cout << number << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Ну и наконец, можно просто запихать всё в исходный файл:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> g_Numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

int main()
{
    cout << "Numbers: \n";
    for(auto number : g_Numbers)
        cout << number << " ";
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Последний вариант, на мой взгляд, ужасен и, при прочих равных, первый вариант предпочтителен.